# iOS - Why wont my audio play in the background?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

Im having trouble having my audio play in the background on my iphone.
my project is [Here](http://musicmenow.com/musicBox.zip) can someone please take a look at it?

Comment: Asking someone to grab your project zip and not even giving a hint as to where to start looking, or what you've tried already, and basically putting zero effort into your question, is not cool man. Let us know what you've tried and what problems you're having, and what particular blocks of code you want looked at, and this question will be improved and you will get more and better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

I have changed to iOS 5.1, because i don't want to update my phone  to a beta version of iOS... There are compile errors in this case.

it would be helpful if you show how is created the player:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:_detailItem
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
              initWithContentsOfURL:url
              error:&error];
```

I am using other player, which is playing in background the radio URL nicelly:

```
    streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:radioUrl]];
    streamPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    streamPlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

maybe the

```
streamPlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

is the key? I forgot, and I can't launch your code.